# How to disable an entire code chunk in knitr?

Tags: r, knitr

Is there a way to completely disable a code chunk in knitr so that it's neither evaluated nor output?

Comment: set chunk options `echo = FALSE, eval = FALSE`.

Comment: @Ramnath Thanks. I'm not sure how I missed `eval` in the docs

Comment: Please either write an answer and accept it below, or close this question.

Comment: @Ramnath, post as answer?

Answer (score 17):

I am answering it. But feel free to close if it is a duplicate indeed

````
```{r eval = FALSE, echo = FALSE}
<your code>
```
````

Comment: The question is _slightly_ different (`echo = FALSE`), so I think it is okay to either close it or post the slightly different answer.